# драйвер на адептер usb - hdmi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, драйвер

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли драйвера для адаптера:
Gembird Cablexpert USB 3.0 - HDMI A-USB3-HDMI-02
моя ос Ubuntu 20.04.1
не могу вывести на экран монитора изображение.

Comment: для начала посмотри, как он определяется в `lsusb`... затем, подцепился ли к нему драйвер в `lsusb -t`... из комбинации первого и второго должно быть понятно,что там за чип, а дальше с этим знанием обращаться к гуглу... ну и со всем этим скорей всего будут проблемы т.к. иксы не любят запускаться на нескольких разнородных видеокартах одновременно и, скорей всего, как минимум, будут требовать перезапуска...